# How do you get a public link to a file in Dropbox that isn't in a public folder?

Tags: dropbox

In Dropbox's Android app, it is easy to grab a shareable link to any file, not just ones in a shared folder. Is there a way to get this link from Dropbox when I'm on Windows (or via the Web) without creating a public shared folder?

Comment: I have struggled with this, too. In fact, you can only create public shortened links for private files through iPhone, iPad or Android apps. This is a major security flaw as you can never revoke those links. The links also reveal your folder structure __and__ they still point to a file with the same name, even if you delete the old one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update:**

This [feature went live for all](https://www.dropbox.com/links/features?source=modal), without having to enable any sharing model or what not.

[image]

---

[image]

---

Previously:

Get the [latest build of Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/install), and you can right click any folder in your Dropbox and get the shareable link

[image: Get shareable link of any folder in Dropbox]

---

*Note: @slhck [points that](https://superuser.com/questions/239301/how-do-you-get-a-public-link-to-a-file-in-dropbox-that-isnt-in-a-public-folder/239336#comment-246188) the Mac version <s>doesn't support this yet</s> - It does work on Mac. You will need to enable the sharing model feature on your account first (it is not enabled by default). The sharing model feature can be enabled by clicking [here](http://dropbox.com/enable_shmodel). Thanks to @emtunc for the update.*

---

If get shareable link for **any folder** is not there for you, please click on [this link](http://dropbox.com/enable_shmodel) to enable it. Once clicked, you'll get a brief notification and will be redirected to your Dropbox folder

[image]

Keep in mind that **this change is permanent**. We are unaware of any way to disable the sharing model once it has been turned on, but you **can** revoke the link by heading over to [Sharing -> Linked Items](https://www.dropbox.com/share#tab:linked-items) and click on Remove.

[image]

---

Comment: Oi that's new! Good that I'm reinstalling Windows and Dropbox ;)

Comment: Even better, the newer version also features auto-update @IvoFlipse

Comment: You might want to add that it currently __does not work on Mac OS X__ (v.1.0.20, just downloaded it and checked).

Comment: Is this on a 32- or 64-bit version? It doesn't seem to be included in the Windows 7 64-bit version yet.

Comment: 'm running on Windows 7 64-bit @nbergus

Comment: It *does* work on Mac... you need to enable the sharing model feature on your account first (it is not enabled by default as it is not yet 100% ready yet). You can enable the sharing model feature by clicking here: http://www.dropbox.com/enable_shmodel

Comment: As @emtunc says you have to go to http://www.dropbox.com/enable_shmodel to enable this feature, for Mac OR Windows.