# How do I 'share' a folder to the public in dropbox?

Tags: dropbox, cloud-storage, public-folders

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you get a public link to a file in Dropbox that isn't in a public folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/239301/how-do-you-get-a-public-link-to-a-file-in-dropbox-that-isnt-in-a-public-folder)

I understand that I can share a single file to the public via a link on dropbox, but what if I have an entire folder that I want to be able to grant access to the public?  Is there a way to do this?  If so, can I change access rights to where they can only download the files within the folder but cannot change them?

Comment: @Sathya, this is so not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: It deals with the same point - share file/folder which is outside the public folder @nreilingh

Comment: @Sathya No, the point isn't that the folder is or isn't outside the public folder, it's about making a folder of files public without using the "shared folder" option. nhinkle's answer is great for this question, but has nothing to do with the "possible duplicate."

Comment: The answer Sathya posted in the question he linked as a dupe _does_ work for solving Kronos's question. However, the _question_ being asked **is** different, even though Sathya's answer works for it. I would propose that either this question be reopened, or it be merged with the other one and reworded to cover both situations.

Comment: @NReilingh - Where does it mention - without using shared folder -> `but what if I have an entire folder that I want to be able to grant access to the public? Is there a way to do this`?

Comment: @Sathya - I withdraw. It wasn't clear to me that the "Get shareable link" feature in your answer presented files or folders differently from files in the Public folder. I should be more thorough next time--apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the dropbox forums](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=17532), there is currently no official way to share an entire folder publicly. You can only get links for individual files.

One potential work-around would be to group the files into a .zip file and share the public link for that. The downside of this is that you would have to update the zip file every time you changed a file in that folder.

You may also be interested in checking out the work of one dropbox user who created a [script to create an html page](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=17432&replies=8) with all of the files in a given public folder, then update it whenever files are added. This achieves the effect you're looking for.

I also found an old lifehacker post showing [a way to get a sharable link for any folder](http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2010/06/dropbox-adds-public-folder-sharing-on-the-web/), but it appears that feature no longer exists.

Comment: I should point out that the thread you linked to is over a year old and is dated. The lifehacker post works works well - as shown in the answer in the dupe post.

Comment: Yes, that works if you use the enable link you mentioned in your post. No so well by default.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox does not presents lists of files to the public. You don't want to "share a folder," since that requires the other users be Dropbox users and allows collaboration.

One way to hack this to make Dropbox work for your purposes instead of getting a webserver is to put the files you want to share into the public folder, and then put alongside it an HTML file containing links to the other files in the folder. Then direct people to the HTML file--they can then click the links you have to the other files in the public folder.

The downside to this is that you have to manage your own directory display. The upshot is that you only need to send people one link.