# How to generate a link for file in DropBox application?

Tags: dropbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you get a public link to a file in Dropbox that isn't in a public folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/239301/how-do-you-get-a-public-link-to-a-file-in-dropbox-that-isnt-in-a-public-folder)

How to get a link for file in DropBox folder so I can use it for sharing on the web?